# Android studio SDK error while downloading

Tags: android, android-studio

After installing Android Studio IDE, I had to download the SDK. But while downloading, It shows an error in the log everytime. The error is:

```
warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/google_m2repository_gms_v11_3_rc05_wear_2_0_5.zip': Tag mismatch!
```

What is a **tag mismatch** exactly and how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these or all:

**1.** Tools > Options > Manifest Cache > Clear Cache then restart Android studio.

**2.** Configure -> SDK Manager -> Tools -> Web browser and then change the browser to your preferred one.

**3.** Try slowing down your internet speed. This a weird solution but seems to work for many.

Comment: 1. I cant open android studio yet it requires that I download the SDK first before progressing any further,so clearing cache wont work. 2. How do I access SDK manager? I tried running the program but it just opens up and closes really quick. 3. I've tried #3 but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Interestingly the 3rd option worked for me. :)